# Typescript and fixed array length (array.slice)

Tags: arrays, typescript, tuples

I am trying to fix my arguments array to a length of 2 so that it can be spread into a function that requires 2 arguments. However, the array comes from a slice of another array that returns the type `number[]`.

```
const twoArgs: [number, number] = [2,3,4].slice(0, 2));
//Type 'number[]' is missing the following properties from type '[number, number]': 0, 1

functionThatRequiresTwoArgs(...twoArgs);
//Expected 2 arguments, but got 0 or more.
```

I have found a solution but I wasn't able to clearly do it in a neat fashion. Perhaps a typescript user can enlighten me with a better way of doing this?

```
const myWorkaround = (t: number[]) => {
  let result: [number, number] = [0, 0];
  t.forEach((value, index) => (result[index] = value));
  return result;
};

const twoArgs: [number, number] = myWorkaround([2,3,4].slice(0, 2));

functionThatRequiresTwoArgs(...twoArgs);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
const twoArgs = [2,3,4].slice(0, 2) as [number, number];

functionThatRequiresTwoArgs(...twoArgs);
```

The `slice` function returns an array of undefined length (event if you know it will become a certain length), so you can't define `twoArgs` to be of a defined length. However, you can typecast it with the `as` keyword.

Comment: yes!  Was going to write the same with typecast in the function call `functionThatRequiresTwoArgs(...twoArgs as [number, number]);` [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=3&ssc=33&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgJwXAngLhmArgWwEYCmCA2gLowC8MxADADQwCMdATKQHQQA2AlsAQAp6LAJQBuAFChIsAGaUYAxAHNGGbPiIMVLdbkIIRlAHwwA3vC5EoShKvGXrt5aLEBfCbIHsfiZCngIag0DBhCiUnEgA)